# Python 2.7 not working -- refusing to serve hidden directly , via 404 Error

Tags: python-2.7, http-status-code-404, jupyter-notebook

[CMD error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7AEa.png)
[jupyter 404 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzBM3.png)

I was able to work fine with python (jupyter notebook) until yesterday, and I turned off the command prompt that was running python. When I try to restart python by typing in jupyter notebook in cmd, it throws a 404 error. I think the possible reason for this is that I was running python as a server and connecting it to asp.net website in visual studio with IIS running the asp.net. So the python server on port 8888 might still be running, and I think that is what's preventing me from opening jupyter notebook.

So I tried the following steps to get it to work, but it throws the same error:

1. Pressed ctrl+c twice to interrupt the kernel (interuppted but still did not run jupyter notebook afterwards)
2. Uninstalled Python 2.7 Anaconda and reinstalled
3. Removed IIS website and tried running python by itself (still not worked)

My question comes down to this:

**How do I get the jupyter notebook to run? Should I try closing the port 8888 and running jupyter notebook again?**

Answer (score 0):

In case someone faces the same issue, I am posting an answer to my question :)

Answer:

Open Anaconda prompt then type in "jupyter notebook"